# compare row date

Tags: sql, t-sql

<2013-03-10>
I wonder if anyone could help me with:

I have a SQL 2008 db where I have the following situation:

a table 'Table' with a couple of columns

`Table.ID, Table.Card and Table.issuedate`

There can be many rows for the same ID with different Cards and these Cards having different Issue Dates.

I need to get out the Card that has the Issue Date more close to:

`Select Getdate()`

Thanks.

Comment: why do people down vote with out a comment?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `DATEDIFF`:

```
SELECT ...
ORDER BY DATEDIFF(minute, Table.issuedate, GETDATE())
```

Depending on whether your `issuedate` column is of `date` or `datetime` type, you may want to use a different datepart.

[Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx)

Comment: Why not `SELECT TOP 1 ...` ?

Comment: Never said that wasn't an option...

Comment: You don't really need `datediff` here. `order by Table.issuedate desc` does the same.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies so far. So far none of the query get the desired result. I have a table the has multiple ID's, one for each Card holder meaning that the ID can be found many times on this table, one entry for each Card. Each Card Will have its IssueDate. What I need is to get the Id, Card and IssueDate per ID that correspond to the most recent entry.

Comment: @user2154834 You should update the question with that information and some sample data with expected output using that data. It looks like you want a [greatest-n-per-group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group+tsql) query.

Answer (score 0):

You may look for this

`select ID, Card, max(issuedate) from [table] group by ID, card`